# Unit/Specflow tests are running 3 times

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, specflow

Our visual studio project has > 600 tests. The project locally executes the unit tests and specflow tests run 3 times whereas in my colleagues pc they execute once (at a 3rd of the time obviously which is a massive desired effect). I cannot seem to find how to make my unit tests execute only once and not three times, how can I do this?

Comment: Which test runner are you using? NUnit, XUnit, SpecFlow+?

Comment: NUnit. Forgot to mention apologies

Comment: you are using `NUnit.exe` to run the tests or you are using the built in VS test runner?

Comment: @SamHolder I am using the built in vs test runner.

Comment: is your colleague using the same runner? Or might he be using resharper's runner or something else? the issue is related to some setup of your visual studio most likely as it works ok on your colleagues machine. I would start by disabling any extensions to VS which might be related, then checking the code out into a clean directory and running again and seeing if that fixes the issue

Comment: @SamHolder I can confirm my colleague is using the same runner.

Answer (score 6):

There is a setting in `Default.srprofile` file

```
<Execution stopAfterFailures="3" testThreadCount="1" testSchedulingMode="Sequential" />
```

Change `stopAfterFailures="1"`. It will runs only one after fails.